# Can we display a image in asp which is stored in hard disk

Tags: asp.net

I have many images stored in my hard disk in C: drive.

Now i made a application which is working fine but it is unable todisplay tha image.

but im my aspx it does not show image.

by the above application i extracted the path which is stored in my database,but not the image at that path.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are these images which your app needs in order to function (e.g. button or trademark logos or symbols), or just images you're trying to display? If the latter you should ensure that IIS has permissions to the folder containing the images themselves, otherwise it won't be able to access and display them even with the correct path.